# "sink in" or "soak in"?

Tags: word-usage, expression-choice

I would like to write the following:

> (...) but some concepts take their time to sink in.
>
> (...) but some concepts take their time to soak in.

I am not sure which one is better, or even if both are correct at all.
They sound alright.

I like the "sink" one better.
I know what sink and soak mean.

Cheers!

Comment: For me, "soak in" requires an object (as in "he decided to go soak in the tub") and doesn't have the phrasal-verb usage that "sink in" does.  So I'd go with "sink in".

Comment: @Hellion See the Macmillan reference.

Comment: It may not be in common use, but as a metaphor, I like "soak in".  Brains often seem a bit amorphous and spongey to me and especially when we're young they soak up ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"some concepts take their time to sink in"

Would be the correct phrase to use, in British English anyway. I've never heard "soak in" used in this way.

Comment: Soak in is wrong. That's why you've never heard it. :)

Comment: thank you all for the information. "soak in" seemed right to me. DOH!

Comment: But [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/soak-in) has the following: << soak in - definition and synonyms 
PHRASAL VERB
1 [INTRANSITIVE] if a liquid soaks in, it goes into the surface or substance that it touches, so that you can no longer see it
_Put some cleaning foam on the carpet and wait for it to soak in._'  [This is the British English definition of soak in.] >> The metaphorical usage is also available.

Comment: "Soak in" certainly makes sense as a purely physical description of liquid being absorbed by something, but I can't recall hearing it used metaphorically. That's not to say that such a metaphor would not be understood, but I don't think it's a common usage (in the UK at least). Whether that makes it "wrong" is another matter.